# How to add a field for numeric values in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want to add a custom price filed just like the price field which can be seen when we add new products.

I can add a field like this

```
$fieldset->addField('price', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('menu')->__('Price'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'price',
      ));
```

But I don't know how to validate it to take only numeric values. Can anyone help me please?

Or is their any other field type in magento that takes only numeric value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add class name `validate-number`

```
$fieldset->addField('price', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('menu')->__('Price'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry validate-number',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'price',
      ));
```

Comment: `validate-not-negative-number` for value >= 0 and `validate-greater-than-zero` for value > 0

Comment: very good answer, it helped me right on time...
But for me I find that if the value I enter starts with alphabets(e.g. abc100), it detects and give error, but if I enter value like 100abc, it fails and lets system to save.

Comment: I am talking about the `validate-not-negative-number` and `validate-greater-than-zero` above.